# gcc -v Segmentation fault:11

Tags: xcode, gcc, osx-yosemite

I have XCode installed (Version 7.2.1 (7C1002)) in Yosemite and have downloaded and installed command line tools. When I try to check the gcc version I get:

```
$ gcc -v
Segmentation fault: 11
$
```

The output for:

```
$ type -a gcc
gcc is /usr/local/bin/gcc
gcc is /usr/bin/gcc
$
```

From what I understand, that should mean that I have it installed so I still don't understand why I can't check it's version. Since I will need gcc for other applications I would like to have it fixed...any suggestions? Do I need to link it somehow?

Comment: What is the result of the command `type -a gcc`?

Comment: Hi Ken, the output is:

Comment: It didn't come through. Edit your question and put it there, not in a comment.

Comment: Note that you might need to install the XCode command line tools.  AFAICR, XCode does not install in `/usr/local/bin`.  And the GCC in `/usr/bin` is really `clang` in disguise. The `-v` option makes `gcc` verbose; to print the version, use `gcc --version`. By default, you're running `/usr/local/bin/gcc`; it may be that the code for that is no longer operational (do you know how it got there?). Try: `/usr/bin/gcc --version` and `/usr/bin/clang --version` and see what you get. On El Capitan, I get `Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)` as the version from both (but some other info changes).

Answer (score 0):

You have a faulty third-party version of gcc (or perhaps another compiler masquerading as gcc) installed in /usr/local. This may be something put there by Homebrew or maybe you installed this build of gcc yourself or something.

A short-term fix would be to modify your `PATH` environment variable so that /usr/bin comes before /usr/local/bin. Or, you could just always specify the full path to gcc, such as `/usr/bin/gcc -v`.

Longer term, you probably want to remove the broken gcc that's been installed to /usr/local. How you do that exactly depends on how you originally installed it there.

Comment: As you figured I have installed gcc using Homebrew. Is there an standard and safe procedure to remove it?

Comment: I don't use Homebrew myself, but it seems the command would be `brew uninstall <package>`. As @JonathanLeffler pointed out in comments, that would leave you with only Xcode's `clang` masquerading as `gcc` in /usr/bin. So, you might want to try updating Homebrew and all of its installed packages and then reinstalling its `gcc`. Or installing a `gcc` using another system, like MacPorts.